# combine 2 imagesmagick resize commands

Tags: php, optimization, imagemagick

i have to resize a image via Imagesmagick and have to create 2 smaller versions of it at the moment is do it like this:

```
<?php
            $command = $IMPath.'convert -limit memory 32 input.jpg -resize 500x500  biggeroutput.jpg';
            exec($command, $output);
            $command = $IMPath.'convert -limit memory 32 input.jpg -resize 90  smalleroutput.jpg';
            exec($command, $output);
?>
```

Is there a way to combine this to just one exec? without starting convert 2 times?

Comment: Downvoted for the unwarranted downvote on my answer.

Comment: I upvoted both of you, seems like a valid Q & A to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the topic of optimising your image shrinking steps, without directly answering your question (like CAFxX, I've never seen a way for two outputs to one ImageMagick command).

One option is to create your smaller thumbnail from the mid-sized image from your first command.  i.e.:

1. shrink the high-res source image to 500x500
2. shrink the 500x500 image from step 1 to 90x90

This certainly helps the speed. I also read somewhere once (I'm afraid the link escapes me) that this doesn't make the quality worse than if you shrunk to 90x90 from full size, and can actually make it look better.

Using the ImageMagick API would work well for that, since you load the source image into memory once, shrink it once, save off the JPEG, and then shrink it again without loading the data from 1. back into memory from disk.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the ImageMagick command line clearly states that multiple outputs are not supported: your only choice to do it is by using the [gd](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) PHP APIs directly instead of the command-line (tip: use the `Imagick::clone` or the `imagecreatetruecolor`/`imagecopy` functions).

As a side node, in this way you also avoid the overhead of spawning a separate process just for imagemagick client.

edit: Additionally, you may want to cache those alternate versions, so that you don't have to regenerate them each time somebody asks for them. I had to do the same on a few image-heavy websites I developed a few years ago.

Comment: GD is to slow for my application, is the ImageMagick API faster then using Imagemagick directly?

Comment: I don't see how it could be any slower. Besides, the documentation for the ImageMagick command line **clearly** states that multiple outputs are not supported.